What is the "Resources Per Executor" item mean and why it is blank in Spark Web UI
As below, when I run a word count spark application with Spark 3.5.0, I could found that the total cores it used is 2 and the memory per executor is 1024MB, I am wondering about what's the item "Resouces Per Executor" mean since we already know "Memory per Executor" and "Cores" per executor from the "Running Executors" page, what info is it about to display and why it's blank?

Also, the "Resouces" item is also blank, why?

